# H2 1.4.185 unable to query by UUID generated from previous server run with Hibernate Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, h2, dropwizard

I have a Hibernate Managed Entity with the following ID

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "hibernate-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private UUID uuid;
```

I insert, fetch and delete these entities without issue until I restart my server.  Once the server restarts I'm unable to find the entities that still exist in the database using basic Hibernate `get` and `delete` operations.

I see the <s>same</s> problem <s>both</s> with my local H2 <s>and with my MySQL</s> instances.  This code is Java 7, and I'm running `dropwizard 0.8.1`.  This problem started when I upgraded from `dropwizard 0.7` which included a Hibernate upgrade to `4.3.5-Final`.

For example:

```
UUID id = UUID.fromString(myUuid)
session.get(myClass, id);
```

This code returns the expected object from the row in the database.  Now after I restart my server

```
UUID id = UUID.fromString(myUuid)
session.get(myClass, id);
```

It returns no records.  I'm able to validate the same records still exist in the table, and the ID has not been modified.

**EDIT**

Actually, this is only an issue in my H2 file-based instance. This issue started happening when I upgraded H2 from 1.3.172 to 1.4.185

Comment: Define "I'm unable". Post the relevant code, tell us what you expect it to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: Added simple example.

Comment: If you found the exact answer to your problem, it's best to post it as an answer to your own question. You can even click Accept for it. After waiting for two days of course.

Comment: @greenreign got any answers ?